# How to run cassandra-stress in DSE 3.2 ? Seems like it's not available anymore

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

This utility used to be there in the tools/ directory for stress testing.
I installed DSE 3.2 and i dont see it. 
Any idea ?

cheers
Matt

Comment: How did you install this? is this rpm, debian, tar?

Comment: Packages will put it in /usr/bin, and the tar ball has it under resources/cassandra/tools/bin. I believe that's pretty much unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Packages will put it in /usr/bin, and the tar ball has it under resources/cassandra/tools/bin.

Seems like that solved the issue, so just making sure we have this as an answer.